# react native ios error build: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SelfieSegmentator

Tags: xcode, react-native

i got this problem when build release from XCode, here is my node_modules:

[image]

First run i got this error:
***<SelfieSegmentatorGpu/SelfieSegmentator.h> not found***

to solve this, i add path to frame work search path like this:

[image]

Then i got error: ***Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_SelfieSegmentator***

Here is my pod build pharse:

[image]

[image]

Can someone help my to solve this? Thanks so much

Here is the project I install from git:
https://github.com/bipmeet/react-native-webrtc-vb

Please tell me if above information is not enough

Comment: have you already set the Podfile to `platform :ios, '11.0'`

Comment: yes bro, i set min to 13, not 11